# Understanding the use of bitwise operators in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate, bitwise-comparison

Can someone explain the purpose of using bitwise operators(like BIT_OR) in MySQL queries. For example, if have a table such as following:

[image]

What is the purpose of aggregate operation like:

```
SELECT name, value FROM table GROUP BY name HAVING BIT_OR(value) = 0;
```

Comment: `val_1` should like a 5-character string??

Comment: `0` is hex `30`.

Answer (score 1):

As an [aggregate function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) the BIT_OR is evaluated as a bitwise OR of all the `value`s in the group. If it equates to 0, none of the value have been set.

Comment: Thanks for your response...I did see referenced page before. Can you explain to me what is a use case of using this operation?

Comment: `HAVING` restricts results. So it `HAVING BIT_OR(value) = 0` restricts the results to where all the `value` for each `name` is 0. Because its `GROUP BY name` having `value` in the result is an invalid aggregation (which `value` is to be included for particular name?). As a result of the having logically `value` will be 0, but the SQL isn't smart enough to infer this. With [sql_mode=only_full_group_by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) (recommended) an error will result for this query.

Comment: I understand how the group by/having works...what I am not sure about is what the BIT_OR does and what its purpose is?

Comment: I'd like to think I've explained this. Obviously you don't get it and asking the same thing again isn't helping me understand you, so I suggest you [just have a play with some numbers](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1580b3844b931290c9e407846498a248) on what effect it has. Keep in mind binary numbers should be right hand side aligned.